# How to transfer Flutter code from VS Code into XCode?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, xcode

I programmed a Flutter app on Visual Studio Code and successfully tested on an Android device. However, when I opened the project ios/Runner.xcworkspace through XCode and built it, the simulator showed a blank screen on the iPhone simulator.
I am fairly new to Flutter, so I was not sure how to implement the Flutter app I programmed into XCode to test on iOS devices.

I downloaded Flutter on the Macbook and ran `flutter build ios` in the terminal. The building completed, but the Runner file did not include Flutter code I wrote from the lib folder.

Is there another step I must take for the Flutter code to transfer into XCode?
Any help would be appreciated!